# Combine matrices in list by identifier column

Tags: r, list, function, merge

The problem attempts to join matrices in a set, by a column identifier.
We can express the problem in the following form:

Setup

```
mat1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=4, ncol =3, rnorm(12,0,1)))
mat2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =5, ncol=3, rnorm(15,0,1)))
mat3 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=3, ncol =3, rnorm(9,0,1)))
mat4 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =6, ncol =3, rnorm(18,0,1)))
colnames(mat1) = colnames(mat2) = colnames(mat3) = colnames(mat4) <- c("Code", "x1", "x2")

mat1$Code <- c(1,2,3,4)
mat2$Code <- c(2,3,4,5,6)
mat3$Code <- c(6,7,8)
mat4$Code <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

mat_set <- c(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4)

> mat1
  Code         x1         x2
1    1  0.6425172 -1.9404704
2    2 -0.1278021  0.8485476
3    3 -0.5525808 -0.9060624
4    4 -1.3013592  0.7350129
> mat2
  Code          x1         x2
1    2 -0.06543585 -1.1244444
2    3  0.03773743 -0.8124004
3    4  3.53421807 -0.4935844
4    5  0.56686927  0.3433276
5    6  0.41849489  0.8782866
> mat3
  Code        x1         x2
1    6 1.0821070 0.08006585
2    7 0.1038577 0.61057716
3    8 2.7002036 0.19693561
> mat1
  Code         x1         x2
1    1  0.6425172 -1.9404704
2    2 -0.1278021  0.8485476
3    3 -0.5525808 -0.9060624
4    4 -1.3013592  0.7350129
> mat2
  Code          x1         x2
1    2 -0.06543585 -1.1244444
2    3  0.03773743 -0.8124004
3    4  3.53421807 -0.4935844
4    5  0.56686927  0.3433276
5    6  0.41849489  0.8782866
> mat3
  Code        x1         x2
1    6 1.0821070 0.08006585
2    7 0.1038577 0.61057716
3    8 2.7002036 0.19693561
> mat4
  Code         x1         x2
1    1 -0.1188262  0.6338566
2    2  0.6128098  1.3759910
3    3 -1.3504901 -0.2830859
4    4 -1.2153638 -1.1611660
5    5 -1.7420065  0.2470048
6    6 -0.9786468 -1.2214594
```

I then want to bind by column all matrices in the set by  "Code". Preserve the ordering. This will yield output of the form:

```
output <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 8, ncol =9))
output[,1] <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
output[,2] <- c(mat1$x1, NA, NA,NA,NA)
output[,3] <- c(mat1$x2, NA,NA,NA,NA)
output[,4] <- c(NA, mat2$x1, NA, NA)
output[,5] <- c(NA, mat2$x2, NA, NA)
output[,6] <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,mat3$x1)
output[,7] <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,mat3$x2)
output[,8] <- c(mat4$x1, NA,NA)
output[,9] <- c(mat4$x2, NA,NA)
output

 X1         X2         X3          X4         X5        X6         X7         X8         X9
1  1  0.6425172 -1.9404704          NA         NA        NA         NA -0.1188262  0.6338566
2  2 -0.1278021  0.8485476 -0.06543585 -1.1244444        NA         NA  0.6128098  1.3759910
3  3 -0.5525808 -0.9060624  0.03773743 -0.8124004        NA         NA -1.3504901 -0.2830859
4  4 -1.3013592  0.7350129  3.53421807 -0.4935844        NA         NA -1.2153638 -1.1611660
5  5         NA         NA  0.56686927  0.3433276        NA         NA -1.7420065  0.2470048
6  6         NA         NA  0.41849489  0.8782866 1.0821070 0.08006585 -0.9786468 -1.2214594
7  7         NA         NA          NA         NA 0.1038577 0.61057716         NA         NA
8  8         NA         NA          NA         NA 2.7002036 0.19693561         NA         NA
>
```

A final point is that the code must be replicable over a large set of matrices. Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list. Use `list` instead of `c` to create a list.

Comment: mat_set %>% reduce(full_join, by = "Code") will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` in `Reduce`

```
out <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "Code", all = TRUE), mat_set)
colnames(out) <- paste0("x", seq_along(out))

out
#  x1         x2         x3         x4         x5         x6         x7         x8         x9
#1  1  0.4291247 -0.5644520         NA         NA         NA         NA -0.8553646 -0.5238281
#2  2  0.5060559 -0.8900378 -0.9111954 -0.4405479         NA         NA -0.2806230 -0.4968500
#3  3 -0.5747400 -0.4771927 -0.8371717  0.4595894         NA         NA -0.9943401 -1.8060313
#4  4 -0.5466319 -0.9983864  2.4158352 -0.6937202         NA         NA -0.9685143 -0.5820759
#5  5         NA         NA  0.1340882 -1.4482049         NA         NA -1.1073182 -1.1088896
#6  6         NA         NA -0.4906859  0.5747557  1.1022975 -0.5012581 -1.2519859 -1.0149620
#7  7         NA         NA         NA         NA -0.4755931 -1.6290935         NA         NA
#8  8         NA         NA         NA         NA -0.7094400 -1.1676193         NA         NA
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
mat1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=4, ncol =3, rnorm(12,0,1)))
mat2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =5, ncol=3, rnorm(15,0,1)))
mat3 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=3, ncol =3, rnorm(9,0,1)))
mat4 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =6, ncol =3, rnorm(18,0,1)))
colnames(mat1) = colnames(mat2) = colnames(mat3) = colnames(mat4) <- c("Code", "x1", "x2")

mat1$Code <- c(1,2,3,4)
mat2$Code <- c(2,3,4,5,6)
mat3$Code <- c(6,7,8)
mat4$Code <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
mat_set <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4)
```

As noted by @G. Grothendieck, the above code gives a warning because the column names are similar in the list of dataframes. Since we only want to join by `"Code"`, while creating the dataframe we can give unique names to columns so to avoid the warning and renaming later.

**Updated data**

```
set.seed(1234)
mat1 <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(nrow=4, ncol =3, rnorm(12,0,1))), c("Code", "x1", "x2"))
mat2 <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(nrow =5, ncol=3, rnorm(15,0,1))), c("Code", "x3", "x4"))
mat3 <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(nrow=3, ncol =3, rnorm(9,0,1))), c("Code", "x5", "x6"))
mat4 <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(nrow =6, ncol =3, rnorm(18,0,1))), c("Code", "x7", "x8"))

mat1$Code <- c(1,2,3,4)
mat2$Code <- c(2,3,4,5,6)
mat3$Code <- c(6,7,8)
mat4$Code <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
mat_set <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4)
```

and then we can use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "Code", all = TRUE), mat_set)
```

Comment: Suggest renaming the columns before merging to avoid the warning that the above code gives.